# LocalStorage Cordova

Tags: cordova, local-storage

for an app, I am using the localStorage with Cordova but it doesn not work. I think that every times that my connexion is off, even if the app is not launched, the localStorage is set to empty.

Is that the standard comportement ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing enough information to help you. Can we see your code? That's the only way you're going to get an answer, I think.

Localstorage isn't a Cordova capability, it's a web standard, so it should work on most any modern phone. Are you doing something like this:

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
```

That gets you access to storage, then you just read/write using:

```
var value = storage.getItem(key); // Pass a key name to get its value.
storage.setItem(key, value) // Pass a key name and its value to add or update that key.
```

That comes from the Cordova docs at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html.